# How does SelectFromModel from scikit-learn select features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

When I use `XGBClassifier` with  `SelectFromModel` the algorithm always returns around five features regardless of the `max_features` value

My question is: does `XGBClassifier` though that there are only five useful features in my dataset?

```
from sklearn.feature_selection  import SelectFromModel
from xgboost                    import XGBClassifier

sf=SelectFromModel(XGBClassifier(), max_features=10).fit(X, y)


#The output only contains five True, all remaining are False
print(sf.get_support())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To only select based on max_features, set threshold=-np.inf.

I found the above text in the documentation [sklearn.feature_selection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html). This means as priority `SelectFromModel` depends on the `threshold` parameter and returns all features that pass the threshold (regardless of `max_features`).

If you want `max_features` fully function, then set `threshold=-np.inf`, in this case, all features pass the threshold, then `max_features` can select demanded features (based on their rank).

Answer (score 0):

You can use threshold='median' to get the best half of the features, then you can call it one more time on the resulting dataset to get the best quarter, and so on. You can use Pipeline for better handling repeated feature reduction.

```
sf = SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(), threshold='median')
```